# Forecasting turnover on retail industries with time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I'm working on a project of forecasting turnover on retail industry.
I have the turnover of different products for a 2 years period of time

My final goal is to forecast a global turnover with and without promotional markdowns for a given period of time.

Could you help me on which method I should use ?

At the moment, I've tried to modelize my problem with only one product.
There is the weekly turnover of my product during a period of about 2 years :
[image]

I have a weekly time series with turnover of the given product.
I read a lot about time series and forecasting, so I've tried to apply what I learn't :

Transform with Log,
Then took if the series is stationary:

[image]

Then differencing series

[image]

Then modelize with ARIMA

[image]

Then predict values, and compare with original values. But it's pretty bad.

[image]

What do you think of it? Do you have any advice?

Comment: Can you explain "turnover"?

Comment: gross sales ? I don't really know the name in english